# Assigning Values to a struct from text file with unkown amount of data

Tags: c

I'm stuck at this where I need to find the highest average number inside a text file with an unknown amount of data.
The data inside the txt is like this

id group score

```
2203 1 33
5123 2 58
3323 3 92
5542 2 86
....
....
```

and the file keeps going.

I'm currently trying to create a struct and then store the values inside of it, but I cannot determine the size of struct since the file has unknown amount of data and it might change every run.

What I tried is this

```
  while(!feof(fptr)) {
    for(i = 0; i < sizeoffile; i++ ) { // here i should add the size or the amount of data.
    fscanf(fptr,"%d %d %d",&p[i].num, &p[i].grp, &p[i].score);
    }
  }
```

I tried adding a counter inside the while loop to get the amount of data but it doesn't work. Im not sure if i need to use malloc or something else.

Example run:
code read the following file

```
1312 1 30
1234 1 54
2931 2 23
2394 2 99
9545 3 95
8312 3 100
8542 4 70
2341 4 56
1233 1 70
2323 1 58
```

output

```
group 3 has the highest average of 97
```

Comment: To calculate an average you need to keep a grand total, and the number of values. The average is the one divided by the other. No need to make it complicated.

Comment: MohmedBm, Who or what text suggested `while(!feof(fptr)) {`?

Comment: @Cheatah Yes i can get the average of the entire file easily, but I need to get which group has the highest average and keep count of that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was taught that i can read a file of unknown length using that. What I understand is that it runs until the end of file. is that correct?

Comment: MohmedBm, it is not.  See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).  Code should test the return value of `fscanf()` instead.  Still this is not the main problem.

Comment: Well I don't understand your problem. Why don't you show a few sample inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, i added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Code could go through the file once and determine the count of records: `N` and then read again, this time saving in an array of size `N`.

Alternative, use a linked-list.

or allocated some memory and re-allocate as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but im a bit confused. how can I exactly run through the file once without using the `while(feof())`?

Comment: @MohmedBm [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70657057/assigning-values-to-a-struct-from-text-file-with-unkown-amount-of-data/70657305?noredirect=1#comment124906979_70657057).  " test the return value of `fscanf()`".